# Users can connect to Minecraft server but time out during terrain download

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I am trying to run a private Minecraft server for a bunch of friends and am using the dedicated server .jar file and running it through a .bat file with the following arguments:

`java -Xmx3072M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar nogui`

My problem is, that I can join to my own server from my own machine, even through the external IP at any time, whereas my friends are unable to join the server once there is at least one person already playing. They keep receiving a `Read Timed out`-error during the "downloading terrain" phase while joining the server, or time out soon after they have successfully loaded and joined the server.

I have whitelisted Java in the Windows Firewall as well as opened the port `25565` in my router through both TCP and UDP.

[canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org) also tells me that I am visible on port `25565`.

Running a HTTP server on `80`, or a Terraria server on `7777` works perfectly fine without any hitches.

---

I have already tried:

- Allocating more RAM to the server (3GB)
- Opening every port to my computer through my router (Exposed Host)
- Disabling the router firewall to my computer
- Disabling the Windows Firewall completely
- Using a different port than `25565` for my server

---

Some additional info that might be beneficial in solving the problem:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
- Motherboard: ASUS Prime B350-PLUS
- RAM: 16GB Corsair LPX DDR4-3000
- Router: FRITZ!Box 7390
- ISP: Deutsche Telekom

---

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: theroy: there isnt enough memory for the other computers to run minecraft properly.

Answer (score 1):

. My theory is that you (the remote host) don't have a strong enough connection to ensure that other users (besides you) can connect to the server properly. Try running an internet speed test. If you internet is normal/fast, other people's connection might not be good enough to download all the server data. Try reducing the amount of server data that other users have to load ( for example clearing blocks, removing various particle effects) or otherwise getting a better internet connection or asking your friends to do so.